# Is this a proper Content-Type header?

Tags: apache-2.2, http-headers

I have a pretty good understanding of the `Content-Type` header for most cases. I understand that for the following four examples, you would normally follow the MIME-type with `charset=your-charset-here`.

```
Content-Type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"
Content-Type "text/javascript; charset=utf-8"
Content-Type "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

... and with images, no charset:

```
Content-Type "image/gif"
Content-Type "image/x-icon"
etc.
```

But what about these two? Should they or shouldn't they include the `charset`?

```
Content-Type "application/x-javascript"
Content-Type "application/xml"
```

I realize it's okay if they don't include the charset, but I would like to include it, if it's possible. They are just text-based files, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Content-Type "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
```

This is redundant. For XML, the `<?xml?>` declaration takes precedence over the Content-Type header. If the XML Declaration is omitted you've got UTF-8 anyway.

I would normally leave the charset out for XML. Given that XML has its own perfectly good inline character encoding mechanism, the Content-Type header is unneeded and can only get in the way by accidentally choosing the wrong type for files without an `encoding` specified that are treated as UTF-8 everywhere else.

The one time you *do* need a charset parameter for XML is when you're serving a non-ASCII-compatible character set, usually UTF-16, where otherwise the parser wouldn't get as far as reading `<?xml`. But it's pretty rare you'd ever want to do that. UTF-16 isn't a great file storage/over-the-wire format.

```
Content-Type "application/xml"
```

The `application/xml` media type is specified by [RFC3023](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3023.txt), and a `charset` parameter has been explicitly defined for it. So you can use `charset` if you want (though as per the above, I generally don't want).

```
Content-Type "application/x-javascript"
```

Is an unofficial type so there is no specification to say whether a `charset` parameter exists or what it might do. This type should probably be avoided in favour of `text/javascript` (traditional) or `application/javascript` (defined by [RFC4329](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt)).

In practice, setting a `charset` on your JavaScript resources isn't necessarily enough, as IE completely ignores it.

Summary of the precedence (highest to lowest) given to scripting character set mechanisms:

- IE: `<script charset>` attribute, charset of parent page
- Opera: charset of script file, charset of parent page
- Mozilla, Webkit: charset of script file, `<script charset>` attribute, charset of parent page

Comment: the more definitive answer, +1

Comment: @bobince, Thanks once again. In case anybody is wondering, Google uses `text/javascript; charset=utf-8`, the WordPress devs use `application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8` for the admin back-end, and most other sites just use `application/x-javascript` or `text/javascript` without any charset defined in the headers.